# Pintool with Java

Tags: java, jvm, fork, intel, system-calls

We are trying to collect the instruction trace of a Java program using pin tool. However, we are not able to comprehend certain behaviour of some of the pin tools on the java programs.

We tried two sample programs for our comparison: `java_helloworld` (which is a simple hello world program) and `c_simplefork` (which is a simple C program which forks a child process).

> 1. follow_execv command line switch : It executes all the processes spawned by the execv class system calls with Pin. However, it does not
>      work in the expected way for the java programs. We observed a
>      contradictory behaviour in the outputs of inscount and itrace pin
>      tools. However, we even observed an expected linear trend with the
>      inscount tool used with the follow_execv switch on a prime number
>      calculation program which is not the same for the case of itrace tool.
>      Do the inscount and itrace tools take into account different kind of
>      instructions for each of them?
> 2. PIN_AddFollowChildProcessFunction is supposed to call the helper function when a child is created. In this, if we run c_simplefork, it
>      correctly reports the process id of the child process, however
>      java_helloworld does not. Apparently, java_helloworld should also have
>      shown the correct child process id because it also does a clone system
>      call. We noted the arguments of the clone() system call in the strace
>      output for both the programs. For java_helloworld CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS
>      | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND |CLONE_THREAD |CLONE_SYSVSEM
>      |CLONE_SETTLS | CLONE_PARENT_SETTID | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID. for
>      c_simplefork - CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID | CLONE_CHILD_SETTID | SIGCHLD.
>      So, is this behaviour due  to the difference in the arguments of
>      clone() call in both the codes?
> 3. fork_jit_tool : 
>     on java_helloworld - 
>     with follow_execv - does not go into any of the methods executed at each FPOINTS 
>      without follow_execv - same as above 
>     on c_simplefork -
>     with
>      follow_execv - goes into all the 3 methods executed at each FPOINTS
>      and prints the correct child process id also. 
>     without
>      follow_execv - same as above 
>     Why doesnt the java program enter
>      the methods which are executed at each FPOINTS , even if it actually
>      spawned a child process?

Comment: Maybe one question at a time?

Comment: @NiklasB. Well, if you can help me with the fork_jit_tool part, that would be great :) The main problem seems to be with the way pin-tool emulator handles clone system call and self modifying code.